# magento logs out everytime I run an import

Tags: magento

Everytime I run an import profile in Magento after about 2 - 3 minutes it logs me out. I have checked the apache error logs, this is the lead up to the log out:

- - [13/Sep/2012:14:58:41 +0100] "POST /index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/batchRun/key/151d60f07b9e68b0023da294f315c3cc/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1" 200 52
- - [13/Sep/2012:14:58:42 +0100] "POST /index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/batchRun/key/151d60f07b9e68b0023da294f315c3cc/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1" 200 52
- - [13/Sep/2012:14:58:44 +0100] "POST /index.php/admin/system_convert_gui/batchRun/key/151d60f07b9e68b0023da294f315c3cc/?isAjax=true HTTP/1.1" 200 148
- - [13/Sep/2012:14:58:44 +0100] "GET /index.php/admin/index/login/key/70f0f08a622f871979b3890c5f769bf4/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1001

In the system log I get:

2012-09-13T14:13:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Convert/Profile/Run.php, line 278

2012-09-13T14:13:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: [0] /var/www/vhosts/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:44

Nothing in the exception log. I have researched the headers already sent issue but nothing has fixed this. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Magento version 1.4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

It's an annoyance. I get it on ee 1.8 during any import/export process that counts the items processed as it goes.
I solved it by adding ob_start() just before that line throwing the error.
I realize I should override the function, but I'm using an old version and will upgrade soon. Hopefully this is fixed in 1.12